# How to find remaining scores from score list after a player is ahead by two

Tags: python-3.x, loops, iteration, scoreloop

Basically need to find a list of integers, representing the sequence of points remaining in the match after the current game; this should take the form of the remainder of the points input after the points for the current (complete or incomplete) game have been removed. The points are simply in a 1 or 0 fashion in a list (where 1 is scoring the point). Player wins if ahead by 2 points and the rest of the remaining scores from list need to be separated.
So for example if I have a list [1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1] The player has score 8 times. But since the player by the 5th point they score they are 2 above his/her opponent and thus wins the game, but I need to find the remains scores which should be [0,1,1,1]

I am able to distinguish the scores but I am not sure how to find the point where the winner arises. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 to some count when you see a 1, add -1 when you see a 0. Once the count reaches 2 or -2, you can stop and return the remaining part of the array

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] == 1) {
        count++;
    } else {
        count--;
    }
    if (count == 2 || count == -2) {
        System.out.println("The game ended on round " + i);
        break; // This command just exits the for loop.
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response but that is much more complex than what I have learned (I am a beginner) and I only know how to use for or while for iterations. Can you help me figure out a simpler way? 

What I am thinking so far is trying to find the "winning point" and then just slide the list from there onwards.

Comment: It is just a for loop, i'll try get rid of the ternary stuff and the Math.abs stuff if that makes it a little easier to follow, edit coming...

Comment: Is the player against an opponent? You seem to indicate that a 0 is a point for the opponent. If so give the opponent a score variable and
`if player_score >= opponent_score + 2:`